# If I make a 3d model in a .fbx format, do I owe any royalties/fees to autodesk for using fbx files in Unity?  

Tags: unity, legal, fbx, import

I'm currently making a game where every format for every asset is either opensource/freeformat, or requires no license fees to use.

I've pretty much settled happily on .ogg for audio, vorbis/webm for video, .png for pictures and openoffice for documents (or .pdf files since they were free standard since 2001?)

What I'd like to know though is, if I make a 3d model in a .fbx format, do I owe any royalties/fees to autodesk for using fbx files in Unity?

If not, does this apply to every 3d model format, or only certain ones? Do software companies like Blender/Unity pay for the privilege to import fbx files so that users like me don't have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using the fbx file format. No.

However, most of the free versions of software are intended for student use only and are not for commercial use.

Check the software's licensing to be sure.

---

I am not a lawyer.

If you're using Blender you're safe.